# Image classification in python getting not accurate prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am learning image classification with tensorflow. Below is my program . for same test image if i am passing again and again it gives sometimes different  labels . It is not predicting correctly

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten,Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.utils import np_utils



classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64,64,3 ),activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(128 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(Dense(10 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy']) 


from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/train',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","surendra","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"])

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/validation',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","surendra","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"])

from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

classifier.fit(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=80,
        epochs=12,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=100)


    from keras_preprocessing import image
    files_dir = '/code/test_image_clasification1'
    files = os.listdir(files_dir)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    for f in files:
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f
        test_image = image.load_img(image_path,target_size = (64, 64))
        test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
        result = classifier.predict(test_image)
        #classes = classifier.predict_classes(test_image)
        #print (classes)
        labels = ["shivaji","kartik","nallayan","surendar","harshita","nagendar","saurabh","rajan","manoj","abhimanyu"]
    indx = np.argmax(result)
    #score = np.argmax(np.round(result*100,2))
    #print(np.round(result,2))
    match_percentage=np.max(result)
    match_class=labels[indx]
    
    print("the image " + f + " is matching with "+ match_class + " having matching percentage  " +"{:.2%}".format(match_percentage) )
    #print(list(zip(labels,result)))
     #print(f,labelsindx])
```

Can any one help me if anything wrong in model training . For information, i have 122 image in train set and 48 in validation set.

Comment: "for same test image if i am passing again and again it gives sometimes different labels" I was not able to reproduce this error. With some sample data I run the code from "from keras_preprocessing import image" on and each time got the same results. As it should be. Could you specify what code you are running again and again and what kind of different results you get?

Comment: I am running the above code in rabbitmq consumer side . Once it completes training and waiting for image,I am giving test image captured live from webcam and passing it from producer side. same image if i take some time its predicting its matching with x class with some percentage ,sometime i=with y class with some percentage .. I have done that test image rescalling also . although i missed it to  post.. still the problem persist..

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the same rescaling factor to your images, this is currently missing and therefore leads to wrong probability predictions. So you also need to rescale to [0,1] by applying 1./255 to your test_image.

Comment: He has done that `test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`

Comment: No, test_datagen is the validation dataset, this has nothing to do with the test_image he is later on passing with result = classifier.predict(test_image).

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. `test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)/255` this will do.

Comment: I just saw that the OP already had this questions and this error was mentioned and now posted this code without the fix of missing rescaling, so I guess the problem will still occur, even if the rescaling is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the loss and the optimizer.

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])
```